# Storing similar objects in a database

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am developing an a house renting/selling application, it will allow users to post rental and houses on sale. My concern is the two objects have some similar and different attributes,for example here is a house on rent can have the following attributes `

```
public class RentalHouse extends Property{

private int numOfBedrooms;
private int payMonthsInAdvance;
private double securityDeposit;
private double rentals;
private String dayOfVacancy;

}
```

Whilst a house on sale can have the following attributes

```
public class SaleHouse extends Property{

private int numOfBedrooms;
private double price;

}

public class Property {

private long id;
private String title;
private String description;
private ArrayList<String> images;
private String province;
private String area;

}
```

Now here is my question; is it good design to have 2 tables for one for `rental houses` the other for `houses on sale`? and what would you advice?

Comment: Consider what things are genuinely *properties of the house*.  The number of bedrooms is a property of the house that is unlikely to change. The price asked by the seller could be changing every day; it's not a property of the house at all. Whether the house is for sale or not is, again, not a property of the house.

Comment: @EricLippert so if it were you what would be your solution to this?

Comment: Moreover: a natural question to ask is "what is the history of asking prices for this house?"  Since asking prices can change, and we wish to know their history, asking prices must not be a property of the house at all.

Comment: My solution would be to **start with a detailed and accurate list of all the operations you intend to perform on the database** and let that drive the design.  For example: "an authorized user wishes to mark a house currently for sale as instead for rent". If that's a desired operation, then it seems like it is a really bad idea to have a solution that requires you to destroy the record of the house for sale and create a new record of the house for rent.

Comment: Consider also how to track unknowns. What if the seller doesn't know how many days the house has been vacant?  (Because the seller obtained the house via an auction, for example.)  You can't say zero, because that's a lie. You need to be able to represent concepts like "unknown", "not applicable", and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep this in mind.